# Using SSH in while loop loses attribute value

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a quite weird problem, can't figure out how it is losing the values. I have 5 server name values in clean_file. Let say if i have to SSH 4th server, restart some application then the while loop doesn't complete the loop instead it stops right after 4th value once it starts the application.

```
grep -v -e"#" $HOST | awk '{print $2"     "$4"     "$5}'| grep -e^windows -e^linux -e^red > $DIRECTORY/clean_file
```

clean_file looks like

```
eclipse server101
itunes server111
appDynamics server100
itunes server102
quicktime server133
```

While Loop & Function for SSH

```
while read -r line
do 
  #check for application status
  mcstat -q -n $name | grep "Processing"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo " works like a charm $name"
  else
     i=$name
     checker
  fi
done < "$DIR/clean_file"

function checker(){
    while [ $j -lt 3 ]; do
       ssh $server 'mcell -q -n "'"$i"'"' || echo "error 101"
       sleep 15
       ssh $server 'mcstat -q -n "'"$i"'"' || echo "error 102"
       echo " I made it work like a charm $i"
   j=$((j+1))
   done
}
```

Output

when all applications are fine and function checker is not called

```
works like a charm eclipse 
works like a charm itunes
works like a charm appDynamics
works like a charm itunes
works like a charm quicktime
```

when itunes on server102 is not running, then checker function will be called & it fails to check for quicktime application status on server133

```
works like a charm eclipse 
works like a charm itunes
works like a charm appDynamics
I made it work like a charm itunes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands run from inside the `while` loop have access to the while loop's standard input. `ssh` normally reads from standard input, so it's consuming the loop's input. To prevent ssh from reading standard input, redirect its input from `/dev/null` or run it with the `-n` flag:

```
ssh $server 'mcell -q -n "'"$i"'"' < /dev/null || echo "error 101"

ssh -n $server 'mcell -q -n "'"$i"'"' || echo "error 101"
```

Alternately, you could protect everything that runs within the loop at once:

```
while read -r line
do
    {
        mcstat -q -n $name ...
    } < /dev/null
done < "$DIR/clean_file"
```